# Does Control in IPhone has Lost Focus Action?

Tags: iphone, xcode

In Vb.net we have that sort of thing right.

However, in beginning IPhone development, by David Mark, the way the author implement removing keyboard when a user tap outside the text box is by turning the whole view into a control and then create an IBaction for that view being touch.

Why not the text box touch up outside or touch down outside? Is this the normal way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is the normal way of doing out of focus. Or you can implement UITextFieldDelegate metod textFieldShouldReturn. Where you call resignFirstResponder for a particular text field.